# H2 database doesn't find Generic H2 (embedded)

Tags: database, h2

My h2 doesn't find generic h2 embedded. I can only see generic derby embedded. I tried changing up the h2 versions but still doesn't resolve my problems. Any thoughts how to find it?
[H2 console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC7MT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list is editable and it looks like a line with predefined configuration was removed.

You can add it back and save for re-use.

```
Setting Name: Generic H2 (Embedded)
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
URL URL: jdbc:h2:~/test (or whatever else)
User Name sa (or another)
Password: empty (or some password)
```

If you want to reset all settings, you need to stop H2 Server process, locate `.h2.server.properties` in the home directory of your user account in operating system, and delete it. H2 Console will be started with default settings next time.

Comment: It still doesn't show up. Now it doesn't even create the .h2.server.properties

Comment: Update: I resseted the PC and worked! Thanks for the solution!